# Rails .all method dumps model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

How do I stop rails from dumping the entire model in the view in the index  method?

Here is my code: 
def index
        @topics = Topic.all
    end

Here is my view

https://41.media.tumblr.com/1bcf55f478094c4ef82cda7676551ffe/tumblr_nsosrw1eRI1r3syg3o1_540.png

(sorry for the bad quality but the dump is at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're adding an '=' in the tag, something like this:

```
<%= @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%= topic.title %>
<% end %>
```

when you want this:

```
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%= topic.title %>
<% end %>
```